# Is it possible to use generic type parameter in its own extends constrains?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to use generic type parameter in its own constraint. It is possible at all in typescript?

My code is here:

```
type Config<T> = {
    context: T;
};

type Hooks<T> = {
    hooks: T;
};

type FunctionWithThis<T> = (this: T, ...args: any[]) => any;

type RemoveThis<T extends Record<string, FunctionWithThis<any>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: infer A) => infer R ?  (...a:A) => R: never
}

 const configure = <TContext extends Object, 
                    THooks extends Record<string, FunctionWithThis<TContext & THooks>>> // problem here
                   (config: Config<TContext> & Hooks<THooks>) => {
    const result = {
        get data() { return config.context; }
    };

    Object.entries(config.hooks).forEach((action) => {
        (result as any)[action[0]] = (...args: any[]) => action[1].call(config.context as any, ...args);
    });

    return result as { data: TContext; } & RemoveThis<THooks>;
};

const engine = configure({
    context: {
        foo: 12
    },
    hooks: {
        log() {
            console.log(this.foo); // this.foo is typed correctly here but I don't have access to another hooks
        },
        test(str: string) {

        }
    }
});
```

Or in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=68&pln=16&pc=76#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAKgPigXigG8BYAKCkqgGNFgIAPYALiiwG5yBfTs80SFAAScOAGsAztjyFSFKgAtRk1h269+4aADEArgmrAUiAOopgCrApRTcBKAAoLN1QBooAOi8BDAE5oJVm8EEABtAF0ASgI8YJANMgFoACUIAFs4ADcIKxtsKEZ6BAATCShU2l9ijAlgXxQENHc9AyNTc0trKTicXvs5KihQgAUoBqgxCBA4JDZw1RHwgqYIErKHLw9vVgakCF8oAEFo-Dxd-fKoAH5KDZ9mY5jy1gQIbN9ucnIaRFqf5HQul80EI2HgCHoTGWRVKUAA8gAjABWEEM7m+g0xWMGWBE4jKhVWsIqcCqNTqDSaUBahmMCDMFlytnBkOAUAAZGw8ZJejgMdiBbdaAC0KxwahMFgWYU8JzubZ5TgTngBlRhX9gRJdAAbNmyfmYtAQNnFbzAbwOaJEKDA4BAhD-CUeYWs9hQLgGnhfeSUREowweVYUiASBzCp1KfGRDxIUkAUW81AUDgcibaCGVxANgwcmp1bO8ZTikVCabpoQADOEloQ7lt-IEoHEIpmy4hQgBGcLO7za7VhxBOl2FJtFkLuTZ+AKRXiDLgz72DW32m0h-Oj4hQU3m1TSphurgc8rpLI5LrYRW8L18MjqtmrNANEGOwHAhyqyjDpisD+Y2NwVgOwAJk9VwDUjFQsx9TFtTgNBLSgwU1V+OBtQgDxYPg5wJBjUQZygAB6AioGw3C4DGMokmKH5fGBQxtRAKAFH2aAEV0NkAEkt0QAByNkFG8bIm2oagQ0o8jgjgCwLggiRsyoLgwOgwZ6FqBxal8VgNMpK1F2xD1oIM+cEjvLczW8ewHyfDxt28XgrNeDC4MtdggA)

I'm trying to create a configuration function for executing set of functions with a predefined context.
I've managed to create a simple demo version but now I would like to have an ability to call my hooks from another hook. E.g. I want to configure my `test` hook to call `log` hook.
In order to achieve this I'm trying to pass a union type as a generic parameter to the 'FunctionWithThis' type:

```
FunctionWithThis<TContext & THooks>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't give me what I want: I still have intellisense for context by my hooks are unavailable. It seems like generic parameter is resolved to `unknown` when it's used as a constraint for itself.

Is it a way to overcome this?

Actually I have even more complex plans: I want to add one more generic parameter to `configure` function and for callbacks and also would like to have an ability to call callbacks from hooks and vise versa. So it would look like this: `THooks extends Record<string, FunctionWithThis<TContext & THooks & TCallbacks>>>` where `TCallbacks` is a new generic parameter which follows `THooks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific problem is hard to solve with just generics.  Luckily, TypeScript has a special magical type function called [`ThisType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#14141](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14141) which allows the `this` context of object literal methods to be specified.

I'd expect your code to be typed like this:

```
type ConfigwithHooks<C, H> = {
    context: C;
    hooks: H & ThisType<C & H>; // Type of 'this' in hooks is C & H
};

const configure = <C, H>(config: ConfigwithHooks<C, H>) => {
    const result = {
        get data() { return config.context; }
    };

    Object.entries(config.hooks).forEach((action) => {
        (result as any)[action[0]] = (...args: any[]) => action[1].call(config.context as any, ...args);
    });

    return result as { data: C } & H;
};
```

This works the way you want, I think:

```
const engine = configure({
    context: {
        foo: 12
    },
    hooks: {
        log() {
            console.log(this.foo);
            this.test("hello");
        },
        test(str: string) {
            this.foo - 5;
        }
    }
});
    
/* const engine: {
    data: {
        foo: number;
    };
} & {
    log(): void;
    test(str: string): void;
} */

const data = engine.data;
engine.log();
```

I haven't looked into how to get your more complex plans implemented, but I wanted to make sure you had a way forward on the code in the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmB3FwAWAJOOAawGcAeGAGijwD4oBeKAbwFgAoKLqAY0WAgAPYAC5YAbg7coOQqTF4oAMigAVHChKrwECspq1xUAPTG1OqHCRQA5Lk02oKBDLkkn7mPrwcAvpPYOPgQSYF5EVDQAVwAnaCYKajoACmDIsXhkdCxcAmJyKgMASkZ6Nk5uYNCoOJIogBswpnLpaTQIMIATAENgbuSS5hqO2Jc09AA6YIFhI18pbn8OBa4AeQAjACsIHmAJiARgGJQIElSIydl8oomkOBiAUW6eHGTk5+AURBKGMpXW5K1BphbruboIEBFADaHy+CChAAYALpIxhQZITTHdGJoEhicEgKFIn70WGIKEARiRU269Xq5yyaCm-CEILBEOomIm2NxRQC0l8fOWFS4cWAo2GdUaUFBLCgPT6GSgvm8ASWgQ1VTCBzQzni4UZsQgyRalRZwjEptaUDucDEFIATP9fJR-ld5Cx-tJ6nA0ANPSLrWaQnB6hAJj6-fYSLdCELA0GoNGJgJQskAEQ4CB0uDp+OJl1e7ip4DJUIxMTl5xoQZF63J21QAC0UAArPyg-NA13BQEgohqgrumidXqJkOAqOEOHIwNxEA)

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you. However I noticed one strange thing: I have correct intelisense in your playground, but for some reason in VS Code and VS 2019 `this` inside `configure` is typed as `any`. Can it be an issue with IDE?

Comment: Probably?  Not sure how to help you reproduce

Comment: I've just copied code from your playground and pasted it to a new .ts file. That's odd because my VS Code uses the same typescript version like in playground: 4.0.2

Comment: Are you using `--strict` or all the same compiler options as the Playground?  Note that the linked issue for `ThisType` shows that you should be using `--noImplicitThis` (which is, I think, contained in `--strict`).  If that's not the issue I'm not sure how to help further.